# Extend Best Line Fit methodology to a Grid

Tags: multiple-regression, curve-fitting

Sometimes, I'm provided with some data, a list of (x,y) points, and asked to determine a best-fit to some polynomial (or other function) that produces the inputs into the function that when chosen, will reproduce most accurately the original data points.

For a line, polynomial functions provide a good toolkit, they are flexible, smooth, and given a relatively small number of parameters, can cover a great many situations.

I want to perform a similar operation, but rather than identify a function that most closely maps to a deformed straight line (where $f(x)=y$ provides a mapping from x to a wide range of ys) I want a function that I can use to define adherence to a deformed grid. What would such a function look like? Is it some kind of matrix object, or is there some analogue to a polynomials that defines how a surface (rather than a line) can be smoothly deformed (without folds or tears) and importantly, an inverse be found to undeform a skewed, twisted or locally swollen grid back into one that has square edges?

It's going to look something like $f(x,y)=x_{1},y_{1}$ but what general $f$, could I start looking at which share the same benefits (from a modelling perspective) as the polynomial family of functions?

Comment: Polynomials are usually a poor choice unless a particular degree or type of polynomial is theoretically indicated.  For a (much) better approach, see our posts about [splines](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=spline+regression).

Comment: If you are seeking candidate equations of the form "z = f(x, y)", I have a large list of such equations grouped by equation type here: http://zunzun.com/AllEquations/3/Standard/

Comment: Yes, this is excellent - I'm writing an OCR tool that reads text from images taken from paper surfaces that can deviate from "square" in a number of different ways, including perspective, rotations, rolls, pinches and various undulations. I see from a quick browse of your site that there is a great range of options to choose from, but will take some time to investigate further. Thankyou for sharing that resource!